# How do I save the contents of a for loop to a text file in python

Tags: python, for-loop, rss, text-files

My name is Scott Reinhardt. I have been working on a program that takes current weather conditions from the NWS's current rss data feed. The program generates every three letter possibility and then loops through each possibility plugging it into the rss url to see if it brings up a valid page or not. If it does, it parses the temperature, humidity and dew point values. I was successful in getting the program to parse the temperature humidity and dew points off of all the valid airport codes, but I can not figure out how to save all of this data to a text file.

Here is my code:

```
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor)
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','mr_anderson')]


keywords = map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3))
keywords = ["k"+a+b+c for a,b,c in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)]

start_time = time.time()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    try:
        a = 1
        b = 1
        for i in range (1,20):
            i=1
            i+=1
            a+=1
            b+=1
            keywargs = str(keywords[a]).upper()
            argument = 'http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/'+keywargs+'.rss'
            req = Request(argument)
            try:
                page_open = urlopen(req)
            except:
                None

        else:

            c=1
            c+=1
            sourceCode = opener.open(argument).read()
            tempraw = re.findall(r'and\s\d{1,2}\s\w.*?',str(sourceCode))
            windraw = re.findall(r'at\s\d{1,2}\.\d{0,1}.*?',str(sourceCode))
            pressureraw = re.findall(r'The pressure is\s\d{1,4}\.\d{0,1}\s\w\w.*?',str(sourceCode))
            humidraw = re.findall(r'the humidity is\s\d{1,2}\%.*?',str(sourceCode))
            temp = tempraw[0]
            temprevised = str(temp).strip("[and F]")
            print(temprevised)
            text_file = open("nws_contourcurrenttemp_data.txt","w")
            text_file.write(temprevised)
            print(str(temp)+' '+keywargs+str(windraw)+str(pressureraw)+str(humidraw))


except Exception, e:
    print(str(e))



print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Everything works like it is supposed to when I print all of this data, but it will only print one line of the data in a text file. I can not figure out why this is.

Thank You,

Scott Reinhardt

Comment: you are opening your text file for writing and then closing it after a single entry, instead of `mode="W"` try `mode="a"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening your file in write mode with `w` when you should be using append mode with `a`, like this:

```
text_file = open("nws_contourcurrenttemp_data.txt","a")
```

To explain, mode `w` is used for writing when you want to entirely overwrite the file. All the contents are removed when you call this. `a` is for appending, the information is added at the end of the file and any information currently in the file isn't removed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the path to the file you are opening is constant so you are reopening the same file over and over again in your loop. Try opening the file only once, outside of your loop.